# Why does my footer have elements under it?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a new website, and I am trying to create a footer that will always be shown on screen. I have successfully completed that but posts are still shown below it as seen here.

[image]

This is how I want it to look (red being the background)


[image]


This is my current footer code..

**CSS**

```
#contactLinks {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 35px 0px 35px 40px;
    background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
    width: 100%;
}

#contactLinks a {
    color: #808080;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactLinks">
  <a href="mailto:me@nathfreder.website">Contact</a>
  <a href="https://github.com/nathfreder" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are actually asking. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], because the code snippet you have shown is by far not enough to reproduce whatever your actual issue is.

Comment: There's a CSS margin below the fixed-position footer. Normal content will be visible in that margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your footer have `margin: 35px 0 35px 40px` which means

```
margin-top: 35px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: 35px;
margin-left: 40px;
```

it should be `margin: 0;`

Comment: @NathanielFredericks If you want to keep the position of your footer but without the posts showing behind it, remove the `margin-bottom` and instead use `padding-bottom` with a `background` to "fill up" the space you want to cover the posts with.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bottom margin of 35px on your footer which causes the distance from the bottom. Just remove that/set it to 0 (`margin: 35px 0px 0px 40px;`).

Comment: why shouldn't this be sufficient as an explanation?

Comment: He used the shortcut syntax for margin himself, so that should not be a problem. Also, I had added the full combined margin setting (in an edit), I guess that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the posts not to be shown, you can try increasing the `padding-bottom` to your footer element so that they aren't visible when under your footer. This will make sure that the footer elements stay where you want to (in case you want them a little bit higher as you've set the bottom margin to 35px)

or else just remove the 35px bottom-margin.

OR

If you want the elements under your footer to look red, you might wanna add another `<div>` and set the CSS properties as:

```
background-color:red;
opacity: 0.5; //if you want to make it transparent.
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
//and set the padding accordingly
```